# Что лучше использовать для парсинга XAML?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, синтаксический-анализ

Недавно прочел, что для парсинга html не рекомендуют использовать регулярные выражения, так как есть специальная библиотека. Ну и вот вопрос: есть ли что-то лучше регулярных выражений для парсинга XAML?
Дополнительная информация:

1. Пишу на языке C#
2. Желательно чтобы инструмент работал со строкой, а не с файлом.
3. Цель: поиск повторяющейся разметки, сокращение ее объема и перестановка атрибутов.

Comment: Если вы хотите написать улучшайзер для XAML, возможно, вам нужен [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn). Это API компилятора, которое позволяет вам модифицировать синтаксическое дерево прямо в редакторе.

Comment: @VladD Э... Раскройте идею. Рослин умеет замль, а не только шарп и вбасик?

Comment: @Athari: Чёрт его знает, должен, по идее. Патамушта идея была в том, чтобы не иметь отдельный парсер в Intellisence (и плагинах типа решарпера), а экспортировать канонический. (Решарпер, правда, от этого гордо отказался.)

Comment: @VladD svick в комментариях к http://stackoverflow.com/q/23106561 говорит, что рослин только для шарпа и вбасика. Насколько я понимаю, светлое будущее только у этих двух языков. Теоретически улучшалки замля можно делать через плагины для решарпера — из него все детали торчат, вроде, и джетбрейновцы не планируют пересаживаться на рослин.

Comment: @Athari: [Тем не менее](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/01/16/visual-studio-2015-cpt-5-now-available.aspx): _We have rebuilt the XAML language service on top of the .NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn") to provide an improved XAML editing experience with rich IntelliSense that is faster and more reliable._

Comment: @VladD Уже любопытно, но из текста неясно, будет ли что-то из реализованного "на базе рослин" доступно в плагинах для студии для простых смертных.

Comment: @Athari: Думаю, что Империя Зла в конце-концов сделает всё правильно. Если уж они вложились в такую инфраструктуру, грех не воспользоваться ей.

Comment: @VladD У MS зоопарк несовместимых технологий по всем фронтам. Был .NET — сделали .NET под каждую платформу с "небольшими" отличиями, потом сделали "общие" библиотеки, сейчас снова делают "общий" .NET. Не удивлюсь, если "общий" .NET окажется или слишком общим, или слишком необщим, и появится что-то ещё. Был XAML — сделали кучу несовместимых XAML'ей для каждой платформы, предварительно выделив классы в "общую" сборку. Были проекты в VS — чуть ли не под каждый тип проектов пишется своя "общая" проектная система. Так что Roslyn — это тоже "общий" компилятор. И рядом будет лежать "общий" фшарп и тп

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Если вам нужно детальное управление синтаксисом, то используйте парсеры XML: новый `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`, старый `System.Xml.XmlDocument`.

  XAML — надмножество XML вместе со всеми пронстранствами и имён и прочим, поэтому любой парсер XML справится с XAML. Учтите, что в этом случае вы получите markup extension в виде простой строчки, а маппингом типов придётся заниматься вручную, если он вам понадобится.
- Если вам нужно глубокое понимание структуры (вместе с markup extension, маппингом на реальные типы и прочими надстройками XAML над базовым XML), то используйте парсер XAML: `System.Xaml.XamlServices`.

  Вы потеряете контроль над синтаксисом (если вы сериализуете не *исключительно* ваши классы), но у вас будет полностью распарсенное в объекты дерево, которое можно модифицировать и впоследствии сериализовать.

Если вам нужна кросс-платформенность, то учтите, что парсер XAML в Mono не поддерживает все возможности (читать: ущербен до невозможности и абсолютно бесполезен), а на разных виндовых платформах свои отдельные парсеры диалектов XAML (читать: парсить можно только XAML родом из родной платформы). При этом в CoreCLR парсер XAML тоже, вроде, не намечается.

Comment: Лучше поздно, чем никогда: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.parse?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

Comment: @VladD А что-то поменялось? После всех метаморфоз фундаментов парсер XAML в WPF так и остался типа-Windows-only (не считая порта за $100500 от авалонии). / Не помню, зачем мне понадобилось рекомендовать типа-кросплатформенный System.Xaml, и при чём здесь .NET Core. В результате всё равно у всех фреймворков по три собственных парсера XAML.

Comment: Хм, и правда. Ну хоть официальный парсер есть и не отпал по дороге.